# Finding a vector with known 2 angles (1 of which lies on plane) and length

Tags: math, vector, geometry, plane

[image: Sketch of the problem]

Hi guys!
I am preparing physical model of a robotic leg on my undergraduate studies and I have encountered a problem that I can not solve.

The problem is described in the picture. I have two angles, one of which is a angle between XZ plane and plane marked with a red color. The second angle lies on this plane as shown.

With the constant length AB and variable value of those two angles I want to find formula that describe position of point B in 3D Space.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about geometry and [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Point A doesn't look as origin (0,0,0) as painted.

In any case, you can find position of point in XZ plane as

```
 B'' = (lAB * Cos(Gamma), 0, lAB * Sin(Gamma))
```

then rotate  B'' about X-axis by beta angle ([matrix (4) here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RotationMatrix.html)).

If A really is not origin, then shift coordinates by z-coordinate of A